# What exactly refreshing does in windows?

Tags: windows

What is the main purpose of refresh in windows?

Comment: huh? a little more effort in explaining what you are talking about might help others understand it too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While refresh has a lot of contexts, it can:

- Reload a web page and not use the cache
- Update the view of the current window with the latest data not in cache
- Force a repaint

Basically, refresh is supposed to give you the freshest view possible of whatever data you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

That's a non-programming question, and must be in superuser.com.

Anyway, to answer your question. Refresh renews all information (icons, text, etc) on the windows selected or at the desktop.